# Ubuntu 12.04: Andorid virtual device: Android virtual device not starting up

Tags: 12.04, android, eclipse

Note: Earlier I had asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343976/android-virtual-device-not-starting-up) on stackoverflow , but got no responses, hence reposting it here.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (x86-64 version) and recently downloaded the adt bundle (adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130917.zip) from Android site. Created several virtual devices from eclipse -> Window-> Android Virtual Device Manager. But the virtual devices are not starting
When I click start for any of the AVDs, a 'starting emulator' dialog box comes, the loading bar loads fully but nothing starts -- even after considerable wait.

Tried to run the emulator (inside sdk/tools) from console:-

```
./emulator -avd <AVD_name>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, when I run this, it throws error but emulator comes up.

```
./emulator64-arm -avd <AVD_name>
emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: lib64OpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
```

What may be causing AVD to fail when invoked from Android Virtual Device Manager inside eclipse? Have anybody faced similar problems?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the tools folder is ~/Software/android-sdk-linux/tools

In the console, before running the emulator command do:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/Software/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./emulator64-arm -avd <AVD_name>
```

Now it should work...

Answer (score 0):

This command worked on my laptop:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/<user>/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
cd /home/<user>/Android/Sdk/tools
./emulator64-x86 -avd <AVD_name> -gpu on
```